# Send a variable from Javascript to Javascript

Tags: javascript, variables, counter

I need to send a variable from a script to another script, i hope you can help me.

The variable i want to send is "campos" that is a counter.

This is the first script:

```
<script>

var campos = 0;

function agregarCampophp(hola){

// alert(campos);

 var data = {};
 data.pruebaId = $('#prueba').val();
 data.deno = $('#subespecifica-descripcion').val();
 data.prep = $('#partidaasociada-presupuestop').val();
 data.tot = $('#partidaasociada-totalp').val();
 // var datad = $.parseJSON(data);
 // alert(data.prep);

 campos = campos+1;
 var NvoCampo= document.createElement("div");
 $('#prueba').attr('value','');
 $('#subespecifica-descripcion').attr('value','');
 $('#partidaasociada-presupuestop').attr('value','');
 $('#partidaasociada-totalp').attr('value','');
 NvoCampo.id= "divcampo_"+(campos);
 NvoCampo.innerHTML= 
 "<table class='table table-striped'  >"+
    "   <tr>" +
 "     <td>" +
 "        <input type='text' size='20' name='articupart_" + campos + 
               "' id='articupart_" + campos + "' value='"+data.pruebaId+"'>" +
 "     </td>" +
 "     <td>" +
 "        <input type='text' size='70' name='articudeno_" + campos + 
               "' id='articudeno_" + campos + "' value='"+data.deno+"'>" +
 "     </td>" +
 "     <td align='right'>" +
 "        <input type='text' size='22' name='articuprep_" + campos + 
               "' id='articuprep_" + campos + "' value='"+data.prep+"'>" +     
 "     </td>" +
 "     <td align='right'>" +
 "        <input type='text' size='22' name='articutot_" + campos + 
               "' id='articutot_" + campos + "' value='"+data.tot+"'>" +
 "     </td>" +
 "     <td align='right'>" +
 "        <input type='hidden' id='c_"+campos+"' value='hola_"+campos+"'>" +
 "     </td>" +

 "   </tr>"+
 " </table>";
 var contenedor= document.getElementById("contenedorcampos");
 contenedor.appendChild(NvoCampo);

data.part = $('#articupart_'+campos).val();
data.deno = $('#articudeno_'+campos).val();
data.prep = $('#articuprep_'+campos).val();
data.tot = $('#articutot_'+campos).val();

}
```

I need that variable "campos" in this other Script:

```
$('._save').on('click', function(event){
event.preventDefault();
var data = {};
data.campos = $('#c_2').val();
alert(data.campos);
data.pruebaId = $('#prueba').val();
data.secId = $('#Hidden1').val();
data.proId = $('#Hidden2').val();
data.subId = $('#Hidden3').val();
data.proyId = $('#Hidden4').val();
data.actId = $('#Hidden5').val();
data.prep = $('#partidaasociada-presupuestop').val();
data.tot = $('#partidaasociada-totalp').val();
data.desc = $('#subespecifica-descripcion').val();

var success = function(data){
   console.log("Success!", data);
}
var error = function(data){
   console.log("Error!", data);
}
//     $.ajax({
//       url:'index.php?r=partidaasociada/get-linea',
//       type:'POST',
//       dataType:'json',
//       data:data
//    }, success, error);
});
```

I am trying to get the variable with a hidden div that i am creating in the first one, but i am getting some errors, thanks beforehand.

Comment: try `window.campos = XXX;` to set the value and try to show the value inside your save event using `alert (window.campos);`. If both scripts are running inside the same window, this should work. If the save script is on another page, you need to pass the variable using query string parameters.

Comment: Both scripts are running inside the same window, i just don't understand what you meant with "XXX" can u explain better? thank you so much.

Comment: Exchange your line `campos = campos+1;` with `window.campos = window.campos+1;` (don't forget to initialise the variable first, `window.campos=0;`). `XXX` should only stand for a random variable value ;-)

Comment: oh, i got it now, xxx is just a var, but i am getting "undefined" with the "alert (window.campos)" in the save event

Comment: now it works!!! thank you so much, u can put the solution in an answer so i can confirm that answer, thanks.

Comment: Please tag appropriately – this is a purely client-side problem, so tagging it with `php` and `yii2` makes little sense.

Comment: CBroe, i'll be so grateful with you if you can upvote my question so i can upvote in comments again :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

glad that worked for you. So basically this would be the solution:

```
// initialise the variable if it has not been initialised before
if (typeof(window.campos)=='undefined') {
  window.campos= 0;
}

// increase by one
window.campos+=1;
```

And in your second script access it using:

```
$('._save').on('click', function(event){
  ...
  // access the previously stored view counter
  data.campos= window.campos;
}
```

Glad that worked for you!